# Require a Proof!

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

So far i have this:
For a square matrix, this means that the (reduced row echelon form A) =                        I[n] and the (reduced row echelon form B) = I[n] thus both the matrix A and B are  row equivalent since two matrices in reduced row echelon form have the same row space if and only if they are equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that $A$ can be reduced $I$ through a sequence of elementary row operations, so there are elementary matrices $E_{i_1}, \dots, E_{i_m}$ such that $E_{i_1} E_{i_2} \dots E_{i_m} A = I$. Likewise, there are elementary matrices $E_{j_1} \dots E_{j_n}$ such that $E_{j_1} E_{j_2} \dots E_{j_n} B = I$. So we have
$$E_{i_1} E_{i_2} \dots E_{i_m} A = I = E_{j_1} E_{j_2} \dots E_{j_n} B.$$
You can invert elementary matrices to reach your desired result.